I want to run PnP Powershell command such as Get-PnPList, Add-PnPField using a python script
I am trying to write a .py to run some PnP Powershell cmdlets using Python subprocess (feel free to give me correct alternative. Successfully installed and run PnP in my PowerShell 7.4 CLI, and I am able to successful connect to my companies SharePoint and run PnP cmdlets and I created .ps1 script, So I know my PowerShell and PnP setup works. But I need to perform some Data transformation which I know how to do best in python (rather do in python), not in PowerShell. I get an error when I am trying to run the pwsh commands using subprocess module.
import subprocess as sp

# This line runs
result_0 = sp.run(["pwsh","-Command","echo Hello World!"]
                  , shell=True,check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(result_0.stdout)

# This seems to work, as I get the pop-up 2facctor login screen of SharePoint 
result_1 = sp.run(
    ["pwsh","-Command","Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<mycompany>.sharepoint.com/teams/<mysite> -Interactive"]
    ,shell=True,check=True,capture_output=True,text=True)

# This line gives me a error
result_2 = sp.run(["pwsh","-Command","Get-PnPList"]
                  ,shell=True,check=True,capture_output=True,text=True)
print(result_2.stdout)

Traceback error:
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pwsh', '-Command', 'Get-PnPList']' returned non-zero exit status 1.


can you check stderr output?
